# Firebase Cloud Functions - Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'core-js/fn/reflect'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

While trying to redeploy a function I now get this error message: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'core-js / fn / reflect'.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^9.1.0",
    "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.8.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1",
    "mkdirp": "^1.0.4",
    "stripe": "^8.137.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

In index.js i use

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

....

exports.StripeEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    cors(req, res, () => {
      //// some code that worked great
    }
}
```

I do not use cors-js package at all...
Where does the problem comes from?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

depending the browser that you are using and the Javascript that you are using in some cases they do not support all the features required by Firebase so you need to at the Polyfills, in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk#add-polyfills) documentation they show you the way to add the Polyfills to your app, the no recommended way to do it is with the core-js library, feel free to do it what you want.

I quick way to solve the error could be go to the directory where your functions live and execute:

```
solution install core-js@2.6.5
```